# Bootstrap "Верстка"

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть проблема с bootstrap. Не могу понять, что к чему? В основном, это касается сетки при использовании разных устройств. То картинка вылезет, за рамки на телефоне, то на планшете текст не корректно отображается и т.д.

Пример кода:

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 test" >.col-md-4</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 test" >.col-md-4</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 test" >.col-md-4</div>
  </div>
```

Мне нужно:

1. Вставить в каждый блок картинку, чтобы она корректно отображалась на всех устройствах.
2. Вставить в каждый блок текст, чтобы он корректно отображался на всех устройствах.

Скиньте пример или статью полезную по этой теме пожалуйста.

Comment: BooDstrap на мужской ум это уже чересчур.

Comment: Вам нужно искать не в гугле, а в оф. документации - Bootstrap 3 - http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/
Bootstrap 4 - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/
там и уйма примеров!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше бы открыли бы официальный сайт и посмотрели бы примеры ..почитали бы вместо того что бы давать задания

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<div class="container">  
<div class="row">
  
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut quisquam id iusto dignissimos iure? </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut quisquam id iusto dignissimos iure? </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut quisquam id iusto dignissimos iure? </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
</div>
```